# JSDOM remove trailing new lines and blank spaces form the string

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, string, jsdom

I am using [jsdom](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom) to parse html

`const data = dom.window.document.querySelector('.row h1').textContent`

In that particular case my data string contains things like `\n            text             \n\n`

I want to remove all the trailing spaces and new lines from the string. 
Is there anyway to fix the string with [jsdom](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom)?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim (20s on Google). I'm sure you want this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const inputString = "\n            text             \n\n"
const outputString = inputString.replace(/[\n\r]+|[\s]{2,}/g, "");
console.log(outputString);
```

will output text, no need for jsdom for this specific case.

Explanation:

**[\n\r]** --> matches a new line, you could just write \n, \r is here to cover different systems which interpret it as a new line.

**|** --> match the first left criteria (new line) or the right criteria (spaces). Represents the OR operator in regex

**[\s]{2,}** --> match spaces but only spaces which are longer than or equal to 2 spaces, if it were only [\s] then you would catch single spaces which I assume do not want.

EDIT

If you also want to remove commas (,) then use this:

```
inputString.replace(/[\n\r]+|[\s]{2,}|[, ]+/g, "");
```

Comment: Hey I am looking for a generic solution as I might have any number of spaces ans new lines appear in the string

Comment: ahh I guess you right, I was actually just come across this two libraries https://www.npmjs.com/package/trim-newlines and https://www.npmjs.com/package/trim-whitespace thinking to use them together to achieve what I want. What do yo think?

Comment: @sreginogemoh I don't know it's up to you, you are the one who's been investigating it and should make a decision after researching the problem and applying an appropriate solution to it.

Comment: I just tested your solution seems work fine. btw these packages doing the same sing pretty much https://github.com/sindresorhus/trim-newlines/blob/master/index.js#L2 and https://github.com/bcmarinacci/trim-whitespace/blob/master/index.js#L5 I think there is no reason to bring two packages for that matter

Comment: I agree, if it works fine that no need to consume more memory with packages... Also if improvement is need on this solution you can easily extend the regex...

Comment: Would you mind to explain your regex through by outlining the parts of it ?

Comment: How would you add the comma to regex? Turned out I need to replace the comma as well..

Comment: try this didnt test: ```inputString.replace(/[\n\r]+|[\s]{2,}|[, ]+/g, "");```, have to go to sleep now have been programming for more than 16 hours today xdd